# pagination in ms.Graph 'groups' in SDK v5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**SUMMARY:**

---

the basis of what I'm trying to do is paginate from groups in the MS-Graph API
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)
although I can achieve it fine using HTTP requests - the SDK seems significantly more complicated for some reason, so the question explicitly revolves around the usage of the latest version of C# SDK (v5 - latest available nuget package for .netCore 6)
(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

```cs
GroupCollectionResponse PageofGroups = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync();
```

**Attempts and Background of Issue:**

---

Ideally I could grab the members from each group on each page using a function like the following - thanks to poster @Tiny Wang for posting the proper iteration method - fixing code below to show existing progress with issue

```cs
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName" };
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "members($select=id,displayName)" };

var pageIterator = Microsoft.Graph.PageIterator<Group, UserCollectionResponse>
        .CreatePageIterator(graphClient, groups, (m) =>
        {
            count++;
            if (count < MaxRecordWanted)
            {
                return false;// stop iterating
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.DisplayName);
                Console.WriteLine(m.Id);
                foreach(User member in m.Members)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(member.DisplayName);
                    Console.WriteLine(member.Id);
                }
                return true;// true means keep paging
            }
        });
pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

Alternatively using the regular upgrade method:
Line "return true" throws a conversion error - Cannot implicitly convert type `bool` to `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>`

they seemed to remove 'nextLink' from 'queryOptions' when they deprecated it to query parameters

```cs
string url = PageofGroups.OdataNextLink;// this URL works by the way - I just cannot seem to find a way to send this link back to graph via SDK

await graphClient.Groups
   .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
   {
     //requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.xxxx = url;
   }
```

although the API reference here works fine - the SDK is not as well documented
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

any help figuring out the upgrade pattern from v4-v5 would be appreciated
the following doc:https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md
completely ignores groups specifically and uses query parameters which don't seem to work
(also the hacky work around of using skip doesn't even work on group's since it cannot be applied to groups only certain cases like users)

in v4 I can use `optionParameters` to leverage the NextLink Obj after grabbing it from the Json response - I can no longer do this - so what is expected is another method of sending the URL to acquire the next page
also being able to grab a specific page from the group iterator without having to loop 'up to' that page - ie pages of 100, not having to check the record of each record in pages 1-7, and begin reading records from 701-800 (i.e. only grabbing page 8) and assigning it directly to a group object

**Code to be fixed:**

---

therefore instead of the documentation as follows:
https://microsoftgraph.github.io/msgraph-sdk-design/tasks/PageIteratorTask.html#example-usage

Something more along the lines of:

```cs
var output = new List<GroupCollectionResponse> { };
var pageIterator2 = PageIterator<Group, GroupCollectionResponse>
    .CreatePageIterator(graphClient, groups, m =>
        {
            count++;
            if (count >= output.Count())
                output.Add(groups);
            return true;
        }
    );
```

But instead of using a lambda on m => {} either being able to use a lambda expression on "groups" or being able to pass an iteration into CreatePageIterator in order to generate the groups via .AddRange

Comment: @TinyWang
the answer you put out does resolve based on grabbing pages individually which is an acceptable work-around to not having the skip function

however leveraging the nextpage parameter in a loop seems like a more permanent solution than having to check the group return size - which seems to be deprecated' (in the case of SDK but still useful for direct http/API calls) to the page iterator function

Also quick side-note, very cleaver use of top to override the 100 page length cap for testing purposes

Comment: ok, looks like you already had your own solution, that's great : )

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Users, after a long time digging into this problem and reading the source code found this solution that works for me

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync(o =>
{
    o.QueryParameters.Top = 2;
    o.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName" };
});

var nextPageLink = users.OdataNextLink;

Console.WriteLine("Page 1");
users.Value.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.DisplayName));

var nextPageRequestInformation = new RequestInformation
{
    HttpMethod = Method.GET,
    UrlTemplate = nextPageLink
};

var nextPageResult = await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(nextPageRequestInformation, (parseNode) => new UserCollectionResponse());

Console.WriteLine("Page 2");
nextPageResult.Value.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.DisplayName));
```

This answers the question about "A way to send this link back to graph via SDK"

Comment: I hope Microsoft will add this approach to the official documentation

Comment: Tried this for `ChatMessageCollectionResponse` and worked well

Answer (score 0):

`Ideally I could grab the members from each group on each page using a function like the following`

-> my idea then, using graph SDK to query groups along with the group members, using `expend` to relate members is supported for [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-7-list-any-groups-with-any-licenses-and-get-the-groups-members).  For pagination, we can use `top` parameter + [PageIterator SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp). I can use it to divide the groups into pages. And in my sample, I have 3 groups, and each query I only obtain 1 group so that I will have   3 pages. And basically, we should then change the `top` and `skip` parameter to query specific rows, but `skip` is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) here. So I think we need to do some other work to paging the groups.

---------update---------

I'm afraid we can use the `PageIterator` to query specific page of groups. I already updated the code.

My code is like this:

```
[Route("groups")]
public async Task<string> groupsAsync(int page, int pagesize)
{
    int totalPage = 0;
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "tenant_id";
    var clientId = "aad_client_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    var groups = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
        //$skip isn't supported
        //requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Skip = page;
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "members($select=id,displayName)" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
        requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
    });
    var pageIterator = PageIterator<Group, GroupCollectionResponse>
        .CreatePageIterator(graphClient,groups,(m) =>
        {
            count++;
            if (count < page)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                groupName = m.DisplayName;
                return false;
            }     
        });

    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
    return groupName;
}
```

[image]
[image]